# get byte size of a String in apex

Tags: apex, size

I have a apex remote action method which expects a string as parameter.But I have to validate if the byte size of the string value that I received exceeds a certain amount or not in the apex code.Is there a way to determine the byte size of a string in apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible cases:

```
Integer prev = 0;
prev = Limits.getHeapSize(); // we are doing it after allocating memory on Integer
String toCheck = '1a';
Integer curr = Limits.getHeapSize(); // we are doing it right in time of Integer initialization to ensure we have the heap size right after allocating space for String
system.debug(curr - prev); // 4
system.debug(Blob.valueOf(toCheck).size()); // 6
```

Blob size counts it as 6, however, I'm mostly attached to the solution with heap size, for me it is more accurate (as you see, 1 byte per ordinary character, 2 bytes for emoji).

I have also added comment with link to the question that I think will be useful for you to check.

Comment: Yes, apparently, Blob size of emoji is 4.

Comment: I would be surprised if the heap usage represents the bytes used by just the characters of the string - see the various answer to e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049398/memory-space-required-for-a-static-string-constant-in-java.